# How can and Android app retrieve, cache and render a custom banner image on a web URL?

Tags: android, url, caching, imageview

I have an Android app where after the user logs in it displays a custom banner at the top of every layout where this banner image is different based on the user's login organization. (E.g. once logged in the same banner image appears throughout the app).

At login I capture a three letter orgID in the user's preferences. Based on this orgID the banner image is stored on the Internet using a URL convention...(wheree YYY is the three letter orgID)

http://www.domain.com/customimage/YYY-banner.png

This banner will be used throughout the app - I don't want to have to upload the image every time the user loads a page - I want to upload and cache the image and use it throughout on every app page.

What's the best way to do this? (E.g. uploading the image just once). Code appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you keep referring to 'uploading' since it sounds like you are downloading the image. I would download the image onto your phone and use it like a custom ActionBar. You can set a custom view for the actionbar, so just create an imageview, give it the banner and set it on the actionbar.

if you aren't using Honeycomb+ or a library like ABS, you could wrap your layouts in a linear layout that has an imageview for the banner at the top and the content below it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can download the image to a directory on the user's device. When you start the application, first clear that directory (so that you don't accidentally use an image downloaded during the previous run). Then download the image to the directory. Now every time the app page changes, instead of fetching it again from the web, just check if the image is already present in the directory and use it, if that is the case.